# Using Razor DropDownList helper to create a dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am just tasked to create the UI part for now.
So I have something like:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        @Html.Label("Default Group")
                        @Html.DropDownList("whatthe")
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Currently no body has written any Model or anything for these views yet. But this crashes on **DropDownList** for me, other simpler controls like **CheckBox** worked fine. How can I get it to show up until later that we add a model?  The crash error

> "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key"

I looked it up, there is a topic for it, **but** my question is just how can I get it to show up for now until later that we add model,etc...

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList("whatthe", new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(0,10)))`

Comment: @MikeDebela good this worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the list of select items on the method.

```
@Html.DropDownList("whatthe", new List<SelectListItem>())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put in regular markup.

```
<select name="whatthe"></select>
```

You'll also need to add in some options to give it some width unless you style it with css.

Comment: Yes but still want it Razor style so later would be easier for other developer to add model